Swift compiler error of firebase storage in flutter app
I am developing an app in flutter, and I used to always run it on iOS(simulator and phone), however since I ran the app on chrome(web app version) and then updated flutter to 2.24.0, the iOS version does not work. The terminal returns error messages regarding the swift compiler:
<<Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Value of optional type '(any StorageProvider)?' must be unwrapped to refer to member 'storage' of wrapped base type 'any StorageProvider'>>

<<Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Cannot assign value of type '(any AuthInterop)?' to type 'any AuthInterop’>>

<<Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Cannot assign value of type '(any AppCheckInterop)?' to type 'any AppCheckInterop’>>

All of these errors occur in the same directory within firebase storage: /ios/Pods/FirebaseStorage/FirebaseStorage/Sources/Storage.swift
I tried downloading the iOS folder from a previous version(of my app) and replacing the folder, however that did not fix the problem. Next I tried running :
pod repo update
pod update Firebase/CoreOnly
pod install
flutter clean
flutter run

However that did not solve anything. Finally I also tried going onto GitHub and downloading the previous version of the code from a week ago(last working version of the project), however every time I eventually ended on the same problem with the swift compiler.Has anyone encountered the same/similar problem and is there a solution?

Maybe helpful, https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/12429

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I am facing same issue after updating android files all of a sudden iOS won't run. I also went through previous commits and found 0 change on iOS folder and tried to fallback on pubspec.yaml packages to previous version. but error still exist. Did you solve it eventually
